# How to declare array with type?

Tags: arrays, numpy

Array,

```
e = []
e.append(12)
```

In this case, I want to make e array long or double type. How can I do this?

Comment: `e` is a list.  After the append it contains one python int.

Comment: `np.array` is the main function used to make a numpy array from a list.It will deduce the dtype from the data values, but you can also specify a dtype..  It is well documented, and widely used in SO  answers.

Comment: A list doesn't have a `type`.  It can contain, hold, different types of objects, e.g. `[None, 100, 12.23, ['a_string',2,2.3]]`